# Unexpected Weird Error Kotlin "Sealed" class usage with 'when'

Tags: android, kotlin

I have come across a very weird error - **kotlin sealed class with when**.

this my Sealed class

```
sealed class Resource<out T : Any> {
object Loading : Resource<Nothing>()
data class Success<out T : Any>(val data: T) : Resource<T>()
data class Error(val exception: Exception) : Resource<Nothing>()
data class GenericError(val errorResponse: ErrorResponse) : Resource<Nothing>()
}
```

this my when class

```
   when (resource) {
                is Resource.Loading -> {
                }
                is Resource.Error -> {
                    
                }
                is Resource.GenericError -> {
                 
                }
                is Resource.Success -> {
                   //some code - working fine
                   // additional code - weird error pops up
                }
            }
```

It was working fine, but I added one new line inside of one block **when**, compiler complains

> 'when' expression must be exhaustive, add necessary 'null' branch or 'else' branch instead

You might say, the error is obvious, just add  a **else** branch. But it seems to be wrong, because, in **sealed** class, there will not be other case, that is **else** branch should never exucute. [Docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html) also says

> If it's possible to verify that the statement covers all cases, you don't need to add an else clause to the statement.

adding else branch will work, the error disappears. But I would like to know the reason behind this, why compiler suddenly pops the error, when I added additional line of code, but was working fine before.

Comment: Your first branch `Resource.Loading` is missing its closing brace.

Comment: Sorry I updated the question, there was a brace, otherwise compiler shows another error))

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `resource` is nullable, that's why compiler requires to add `'null' branch or 'else' branch`